# Merging shapefiles with different polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

So I was given two different shapefiles for the same region, one produced by a state planning agency[image: State Agcy. Shapefile]  and the other produced by a municipal agency.[image: Munic. Agcy Shapefile] I was tasked with updating the state-made shapefile on ArcGIS so it better corresponds with the municipal one. Is the best way to go about this with the identity analysis feature or with writing code, because the generated output is a more clustered map with even smaller polygon regions. [image]
any idea how to go about this? should I just do it in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]."Merge" isn't really the right description for this process, which is more like an Overlay.  I've cleaned up country/admin1 datasets with poor registration using a topology in a file geodatabase.

Comment: Conflating some of those differences is probably going to require specific direction from your management (which has precedence when there's serious conflicts). You really need to choose for which environment you want a solution first, since adding QGIS late to an ArcGIS question makes this multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "better corresponding"? So long as there are the same number of polygons, covering roughly the same area, and we are assuming the municipal layer is more accurate, (and this is only if the metadatat/fields are different within the layers), convert the state layer polygon to point, and then do a spatial join to the municipal layer.  This way, you will maintain the mapping of the municipal layer and simply add the state data to each corresponding polygon.